# Strong principle of mathematical induction proof clarification

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I have a question on the final step of the following proof:

> Suppose that $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N^*}$ is a sequence of real numbers defined recursively by $a_1 = 1,
> a_2 = 2$ and $a_n$ = $\frac{a_{n−1}}{a_{n−2}}$ for n ≥ 3. Prove that $$\forall n\in \Bbb N^*,a_n=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }n \equiv 1, 4 \mod 6\\2\text{ if }n \equiv 2, 3 \mod 6\\ \frac12 \text{ if } n \equiv 0, 5 \mod 6\end{cases}$$

**The proof**
Proof. We use the Strong Principle of Mathematical Induction. Since $a_3 = a_2 /a_1 = 2,
a_4 = a_3 /a_2 = 2/2 = 1, a_5 = a_4 /a_3 = 1/2$ and $a_6 = a_5 /a_4 = (1/2)/1=1/2$, the statement is
true for 1 ≤ n ≤ 6. Assume that the result is true for every integer i with 1 ≤ i ≤ k, where
k ≥ 6. We establish the result for $a_{k+1}$ . Now $a_{k+1}$ = $\frac{a_k}{a_{k−1}}$ . We consider six cases.
Case 1. k + 1 ≡ 5 (mod 6). Then $a_{k+1}$ = $\frac{ak}{a_{k−1}}= 1/2.$

(The remaining cases are handled in a similar manner.)

Case 2. k + 1 ≡ 4 (mod 6).

...

My **question** is on the very last step, where it says that $a_{k+1}$ = $\frac{ak}{a_{k−1}}= 1/2.$

How are $a_k$ and $a_{k-1}$ determined? I get that since we proved it for all 6 of ${a_1,a_2,...,a_6}$, then that covers all possible numbers mod 6, so all $a_i$s up to $a_k$ and hence $a_k$ itself are true. But how do we arrive at 1/2, in other words, what are the values for $a_k$ and $a_{k-1}$ in Case 1 (Should obviously be 1 and 2 respectively, but i just don't see the exact thought process)?

Comment: If $k+1\equiv5\pmod6$ (i.e. in your case 1) then $k\equiv4\pmod6$ and $k-1\equiv3\pmod6$ hence by induction hypothesis, $a_k=1$ and $a_{k-1}=2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! One more question: In the case when k+1 ≡ 0 (mod 6), would k ≡ 1 (mod 6) and k-1 ≡ 2 (mod 6)? Is that how negatives in mod work?

Comment: @AnneBauval Or would it be k ≡ 5 (mod 6) and k-1 ≡ 4 (mod 6)?

Comment: Your second guess is right: k ≡ -1 ≡ -1+6 = 5 (mod 6) and k-1 ≡ 5 - 1 = 4 (mod 6).